# Center DIV on Android & iPhone

Tags: android, html, css, iphone, center

I need to get a DIV that I have to center both in 320/480 views on BOTH iPhones and Android phones.

Below are my tests.

It seems NOT to center on an Android Phone.

**Test Page** - 
http://mymsaa.org/publications/motivator/winter-spring16/

**iPhone Example** - http://mymsaa.org/example_2.png

**Android Phone Example** - http://mymsaa.org/example.png

This is my HTML for the DIV...

```
<div class="motiv_cover">
<a href="http://mymsaa.org/publications/motivator/winter-spring16/download/"><img src="http://mymsaa.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/winter-spring16-cover.gif" alt="The Motivator: Winter/Spring 2016 Cover" title="The Motivator: Winter/Spring 2016" border="0"></a>

<a href="http://mymsaa.org/publications/motivator/winter-spring16/download/">View/Download PDF</a></div>
```

This is my CSS for the DIV in 320/480 views...

```
.motiv_cover {
font-size: 13px;
color: #012e63;
width: 175px;
text-align: center;
float: none;
position: relative; left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0 auto; top: 0;
padding: 10px; 
padding-bottom: 0px;
background-color: #e1e3f0; 
border: 1px solid #012e63; 
margin-bottom: 15px;}
```

What is the best practice for this?

Comment: There is no need for `position: relative, top, left, right` The minimal code is `float: none` (to cancel floating) and `margin: 0 auto` to center. I think your code is fine but the breakpoint did not happen in Android - check the media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the full code? Do you have the correct meta tag for the viewport? Ie:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Yes I do have that meta tag. The full code is A LOT of code since it calls out to scripts and CSS code for a website that is over 500 pages big.

Comment: Just checked it out on my phone and looks like you sorted it, but just a heads up that your page is overflowing horizontally